# Decimal zeros at the end are not show. Anyone help me please

Tags: javascript

alert(10.1000);

I need to show the 3 zeros at the end after decimal point.
The last 3 zeros are cleared by default.

Comment: How does jquery come in to this?

Comment: I find a solution, I added a text field and set it as hidden and call from hidden field. this will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the javaScripts ***.toFixed(n)*** method where `n` refers to the number of Decimals.

```
alert(10.1000.toFixed(4));
```

*For arbitrary inputs you can try this way,*

***HTML :***

```
<input type="number" id="inputTextbox" />
```

***javaScript :***

```
inputTextbox.onblur = function(){
    ShowNumber(this.value);
};

function ShowNumber(num){
    var decimalNumLength = num.split('.')[1].length;
    alert(Number(num).toFixed(decimalNumLength));
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/je0bhk8v/)

Comment: `toFixed(4)` actually

Comment: Yeah this will work. But the count of zeros are not static. so this method is not help for my case.

Comment: then you should have a script that'll count the number of zeros and then use `.toFixed(count)` to show the appropriate value.

Comment: Actually, I'm using php function to pass this number and I get the number in function as 10.1.

Comment: The number correctly passing through function and not get zeros inside the function.